# Calling Microsoft::WRL::Make for a constructor with more than 9 arguments

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, wrl

[`Microsoft::WRL::Make` seems to be defined with a maximum of 9 arguments that will get forwarded to the object's constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244883.aspx). `std::tuple` is an obvious solution, but far from ideal. Is there a more elegant way of solving this problem?

*If any maintainers of WRL are lurking around, please add variadic template support to `Make` (as well as `RuntimeClass`, etc. while you're at it)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, here's my current working solution:

```
template <typename... Types>
MyClass(std::tuple<Types...> args) :
    MyClass(args, std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, sizeof...(Types)>())
{
}

template <typename... Types, size_t... Indices>
MyClass(std::tuple<Types...>& args, std::integer_sequence<size_t, Indices...>) :
    MyClass(std::get<Indices>(std::move(args))...)
{
}
```

Constructed with

```
auto ptr = Make<MyClass>(std::forward_as_tuple(...));
```

Far from ideal, but worst case scenario it'll do...